# Jssor slide out each caption

Tags: transition, slide, jssor, caption

I downloaded and used Jssor slide from this source : http://www.jssor.com/demos/introduction-slider.html

And how can I slide each caption in a slide.

Ex : in slide 1, caption A fade in, then caption A fade out after 3s and caption B fade in with position is same caption A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

't3' is for play out as well as 't2', but 't3' plays after 't' immediately.

And you can set 'd3' to 3000 to specify the delay (3s).

```
<div u=caption t="yourfadetransitionname" t3="yourfadetransitionname" d3="3000" ...
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-caption-jquery.html